# how to view data column wise in unix

Tags: database, unix, multiple-columns

- I am working on `Unix` box where I need to access `SQLPlus`.
- I have a table where it has more than 10 (Ten) columns.
- When I trigger the query `select * from (Table name)` it gives me lot
  of result where I am confused with which data belongs to which
  column.

Is there any way to display the data without merging each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using below in effective way:-
Normally I use as below

```
set line 200
set pagesize 10 

select * from table;
```